# Entering int in a string variable

Tags: java, string, int

I ask the user to enter a name(String) and age(int), so if the user enters a number in the name space it "crashes". So what can i do to stop the program from crashing. Im using java.

Comment: Please provide relevant code and error stack trace to make the question answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you casting the input to a int, or leaving it as string?
Once you take it in from the input you need to convert it from the string to an int. 
int age = Integer.parseInt(ageInput);